# PHP - unable to rename a file - "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: php

I have a problem when ill try to rename a (long) filename with PHP on a Windows 2012 Server.

The filename is:

```
WG VERS3220 - ObNr 1370 - Datum 25.01.2018 Sparte Bündel  Summe 0,00  Datum 25.01.2017  Objekt 1342  WEG Guild 44-46.htm
```

I am always receiving the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   (code: 123)

But when ill check for valid filenames:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#naming_conventions

i do not see any problem with not supported characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: dayum that's a long ass file name, why the need? maybe it's the full stops, try but using date format in d-m-y rather than d.m.y

Comment: Because i am not creating the file. i need to handle such long filenames.

Comment: I think there is a problem in date format i.e. contains fullstops

Comment: what exactly do you mean (so i am able to rename it manually and test it out)

Comment: as in d.m.y => d-m-y

Comment: i manually now converted all "." to "-" - but still receiving the same error

Comment: It's probably the umlaut. Which PHP version is this and what character encoding are you using?

Comment: already changed the "umlaut" too ;) PHP Version is 7.2.2 - if i manually change the name to "test" for example. Everything works fine. Ill need to rename the file. If ill do it manually with "cmd", everything works fine aswell.

Comment: I second the umlaut. Perform this on the filename string (eg. $string): $string= str_replace('ü', '&uuml', $string);

Comment: thats not working. i am unable to "rename" the file. The file is already there. I would like to rename it (to something without any umlaut, and a shorter name) - when ill remove the last characters (Guild 44-46) - it works now. Could that be a problem with the length? I thought the maximum file length in windows is 255?

Comment: Ah that's surprising. Have you found a definite max length? Might be a good starting point for more research.

Comment: One thing I'm reading is that the max length is actually the entire path for some api's.

Comment: If your file is somewhere deep in a heavily nested directory structure, you might hit a max. char lenth.  You might try changing the location of the file to a (few) folders higher in the structure and retry your operation on the file. GL.

Comment: Are you just using PHP's `rename()` function? It's working fine for me on a Windows 7 (rather than server 2012, granted) dev box. Interestingly though, CLI has problems when using `dir/p` on the directory with that filename in ... but I can `REN` it fine.

Comment: Thanks - ill found the problem now. As you correct suggested, the problem is the whole filename including path - if its more then 255 characters, you are struggle with the following problem. We have to fix the path length, and then everything should work!